# Alternative sites devoted to UI micro features

Tags: design-patterns, resources, master-details

[Little Big Details](http://www.littlebigdetails.com) is a microblog that shows screenshots of various user-interfaces, highlighting the the "little" things that make a "big" difference. For example, the [latest entry](http://littlebigdetails.com/post/7889641562/webkit-when-entering-text-into-a-password-field) highlights a little icon in password fields indicating that the caps lock key is on.

Are there any other resources similar to this one from which I can draw inspiration?

Comment: I'd like to keep this open and see if we get some interesting answers. It's a great question even if the question body isn't very big.

Comment: I think actually the User Experience Stack Exchange covers some interesting little details and nuances of interface design that might not otherwise get a lot of attention.

Answer (score 2):

LittleBigDetails is the only site of it's type that I'm aware of (which is why I really like it)... but you can also find good "real world" micro feature examples in some of the UX Pattern Libraries.  Some of my favorites are:

- [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main)
- [UI-Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/)
- [Pattern Tap](http://patterntap.com/)

A complete list can be found in the [Yahoo! Design Pattern Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/about/libraries.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Deisgn Shack's UI Gallery](http://designshack.co.uk/gallery/interface/all/all/all). It has a nice collection of micro interfaces.

Comment: That's a new source for me; thanks for sharing! You do need to be careful about what elements you take from it, though, as many of the examples are shown as good design, not good UI.  For instance, [the Simple Dial](http://designshack.co.uk/design/simple-dial) is shown as a "stunning" element, but rotational controls are rarely a good idea in interface design **unless** on a touch screen because they're too hard to control.  Even on a touch screen, standard sliders are better as it's easier for a user to precisely maneuver in a straight line than around a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two similar sites I like like:

- [Subtle Patterns](http://www.subtlepatterns.com)
- [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com)

Comment: Why do you like these sites? What's good about them? How do they contribute to UI micro features?

Comment: -1. I think you misunderstood the question, since none of the websites is related to UI micro features.

Comment: subtle patterns is more about visual design (decorative background patters) rather than interaction design patterns. That said, Dribbble is a nice mix of visual design and UI design and certainly an option to consider.